# StreamReader throws System.IO.FileInfo[] exception when reading files

Tags: .net, vb.net, streamreader

Every time I try to read a file using a `StreamReader`, it is throwing the following exception:

> System.IO.FileInfo[] cannot be found.

Here is my code:

```
Dim dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)

Dim files As FileInfo() = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

Dim sr = New StreamReader(TextBox1.Text & "/" & dinfo.GetFiles.ToString)
```

Further in my code I have this sample, I don't know if it's relevant but just in case:

```
Dim dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)

Dim files As FileInfo() = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)

ListBox1.Items.Clear()
For Each file As FileInfo In files
    ListBox1.Items.Add(file.Name)
 Next
```

I'm trying to pass all the found .txt files to the `StreamReader` so the `StreamReader` can read all the found .txt files one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `dinfo.GetFiles.ToString` like that. This will return `System.IO.FileInfo[]` whilst a [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) is expecting a path or a stream. I think in this case a path.

Also rather than concatenating strings together to make a path up consider using [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx). Although in the end I don't think you will actually need this but it's worth reading up on it.

I would also consider implementing [Using](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement) when using a `StreamReader`:

> Sometimes your code requires an unmanaged resource, such as a file handle, a COM wrapper, or a SQL connection. A Using block guarantees the disposal of one or more such resources when your code is finished with them. This makes them available for other code to use.

Based on your comment, I think what you are after is something like this:

```
Dim dinfo As New DirectoryInfo(TextBox1.Text)
For Each f In dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    Using sr As New StreamReader(f.FullName)
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine())
        End While
    End Using
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is quite simple if i'm not mistaken is due to the fact your passing an array to a `StreamReader` but the `StreamReader` is made to read one file at a time.

What I present here is using your ListBox approach but this isnt the recommended version.

Sub to add all *.txt files to listbox:

```
Public Sub AddToList(ByVal pather As String)
    Dim Names As String() = Directory.GetFiles(pather, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ' Display all files.
    For Each name As String In Names
        ListBox1.Items.Add(name)
    Next
End Sub
```

Then sub to read all *.txt one by one:

```
Public Sub ReadAllTxt()
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        Console.Write(File.ReadAllText(item))
    Next
End Sub
```

A nicer approach would be to read directly as we go through the files:

```
Public Sub ReadAllTxt(ByVal pather As String)
    Dim Names As String() = Directory.GetFiles(pather, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ' Display all files.
    For Each name As String In Names
        ListBox1.Items.Add(name)
        Console.Write(File.ReadAllText(name))
    Next
End Sub
```